# populate a combobox with attributes of a selected xml node using c#

Tags: c#, .net

Im using c#.net windows form application. I have a xml file. I have loaded the node names of that xml file into a treeview. Now my task is , when I select a particular node from the treview, I should be able to display its attributes in a combo box. Please help.

Comment: Is the problem to fill the combobox, to get the attributes, or both? How did you load the XML file? Using XmlDocument or XmlReader?

Comment: Can you show us the XML and explain what you want to extract from it??

Comment: This is my xml file
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <languages>
- <language>
  <key>abc</key> 
  <value>hello how ru</value> 
  </language>
- <language>
  <key>def</key> 
  <value>i m fine</value> 
  </language>
- <language>
  <key>ghi</key> 
  <value>how abt u</value> 
  </language>
- <name>
  <firstname>asd</firstname> 
  <middlename>aaaaaaaaa</middlename> 
  </name>
  </languages>

Now if I select key, it should show abc

Answer (score 0):

When populating each XML node in the treeview, store the actual XPATH as a tag of that treeview node. On click, pick up the tag value, query the XmlDocument object and display your attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe saeed is lazy to create it by himself.

@Raj - you don't have to store XPATH as a tag, you can store the node itself there.